# Angular JS ng-bind with special character

Tags: angularjs

I want to bind a field from database using ng-bind. The field name is for eg: XYZ/ABC. I am using ***td ng-bind="XYZ/ABC"*** I am getting Nan printed. How do I escape the / in the field name while binding.

Note:  I am getting multiple object from DB. I have to print all the objects in a rows.Hence binding all the field names to td in table.

Comment: Provide your code, please.

Comment: please provide your code, I tried using this

$scope.test = "XYZ/ABC";
 <table>
       <tr>
           <td ng-bind="test"></td>
       </tr>
   </table>

Answer (score 0):

Do not bind this property directly into your scope/controller, but use a wrapping object for it.

```
// In the model
$scope.fields['XYZ/ABC'] = 42;

// In the view
<td ng-bind="fields['XYZ/ABC']">
```